# Split text message into chunks of 30 chars limit with suffixed (k/n)

Tags: algorithm

There is a text-messaging service, that sends messages to the user that can be at most 30 characters long. Create a function to splits the text into chunks so that it can be sent in multiple messages.

Each chunk can be:

- up to 30 chars long
- no word should be split in the middle.
- each chunk has to have its order suffixed in the form of '(k/n)',

  e.g  "this is from chunk (1/2)", "this is the second chunk (2/2)"
- if the text provided to the function is within 30 chars limit, no ordering should be suffixed.
- Space wouldn't be considered as the part of word.
- No words will have up to length including suffixes.
- There can be N = 1000 characters.

Solution:- I am thinking DP/Greedy might solve the no of chunks without suffix (n/k), how to know the total no of suffix there beforehand.

Comment: First things first: How do you define "word"? What should happen if a single word is longer than the character limit?

Comment: that's guaranteed to be under the character limit, and word is anything space apart. (Space is not counted under the character limit)

Comment: From what I understood, the only case where you do not need to suffix the order is when you only have 1 chunk

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the greedy approach that would be correct. More rigorously, we know by induction:

Base case:
Text message can fit into one message (<= 30 chars). In this case the greedy approach would be the same as the optimal solution (one message), thus it is correct.

Inductive step:
Let's assume that for a message that requires n messages to send, that the greedy solution is optimal. Now let's prove this for the n+1 case. With the greedy approach, everything except for the last 5 characters (taken up by the message numbering) will fit in the first n messages. We are then left with <= 25 characters, these characters will then fit into one message which is the optimal solution as shown by the base case.

--

Let's move forward and talk about how we would find out the number of suffixes we need. We have the case in which we would need no suffixes (fits into one message), this would happen if and only if the message is <= 30 characters.

However, if it is more, this is where it gets tricky. We now know that the message must be <= 25 characters to fit in the suffix. So now, we must iterate through the complete message that we are trying to send and check at the 25 character mark. If that is a space, perfect, we increase the number of suffixes we need by one, discard the space and everything before it and continue on our way. However, if it is not a space, the problem specifies that we need every word to be complete. So, therefore we have to backtrack until we find a space, then that would be the cut and the process would continue the same as before. We would continue this process until the entire message has been processed.

Comment: Considering 5 characters as prefix won't always work. What if there are multiple digit chunks like 10 chunks, so the suffix (1/10) is no longer 5 characters and this particular chunk now is 31 characters and violating the conditions needed.